# allow only alphabets and underscore using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am allowing a string to contain only alphabets and underscore,but is i enter fist character as alphabet or underscore and later if i put any invalid character then this validation is being done.I have done validation as follows:

```
function permission_validate()
{var permission=document.permissionForm.permission.value;var allowedStr=/[A-Za-z_]/;

if(!allowedStr.test(permission)){document.getElementById("permission_Er").innerHTML="* Required field can contain Only A-Z/az/_";

document.permissionForm.permission.focus();return false;}else{return true;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct regex to use would be

```
/^[a-zA-Z\_]+$/g
```

^ matches beginning
$ matches end
g matches the whole string.

Comment: Don't think you need backslash before underscore. Underscore is not a resreved character in regex

Comment: I know, I just always use backslashes behind characters that aren't letters to be on the safe side. :P

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-z_]+$/gi
```

**Note**: You need anchors ^ and $ and + to accept one of more characters of alphabets and underscores.